# SFTP Access on CentOS Server

Tags: centos, sftp

I have a CentOS server with a plesk control panel installed, I used to login using SFTP with the root password to manage the files. However, and all of a sudden, I am not able to access the server using SFTP and I get this error when using CuteFTP

```
ERROR:>     [4/18/2012 5:18:31 PM] Connection to the server was lost, and the operation could not be performed.
ERROR:>     [4/18/2012 5:18:31 PM] Can't connect to localkicks.com:22. SFTP21 error = #7. 0
```

I tried restarrting sshd on linux but with no luck, how do I troubleshoot this?

Appreciate the help.

Yehia A.Salam

Comment: Does CUTE have an option for SCP fallback? Might want to give that a try if it exists.

Comment: Can you login via ssh?  Do you have an IPS tool installed? (denyhost/fail2ban)

Comment: yes I can login through ssh, Actually I tried WinSCP (CuteFTP does not have a SCP fallback) and It worked. But why in the first place the sftp is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried WinSCP and it works now, however i'm not sure why in the first place the sftp was not working

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question, but it's good to know why things fail. http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10353.aspx might help. WinSCP is excellent, I'd use that over CuteFTP but I have a strong bias against FTP in general. You might also want to check out lftp, an awesome command-line s/ftp client.